# The request works on phpadmin but not in my php code

Tags: php, sql, derived-table

Let me please show an other example ...
I can't be able to create this view in php (whereas i can in phpmyadmin)

```
$sql="CREATE VIEW ratings.rtgemissfitch AS
SELECT derivedtable. ISIN
FROM
(SELECT ISIN, MAX(Date_Notation_Emission) FROM ratings.ratingsemissionfitch as derivedtable GROUP BY ISIN) ";
```

But i can do this in php :

```
$sql="CREATE VIEW ratings.rtgemissfitch AS
(SELECT ISIN, MAX(Date_Notation_Emission) FROM ratings.ratingsemissionfitch as derivedtable GROUP BY ISIN) ";
```

I really don't understand..First of all, sorry for my english, i'm french..
I really don't understand why the request, which runs on phpadmin, doesn't work in my php code..probaby the derivated table...
So, i'm looking to get the last rating Fitch :
The SQL request in phpmyadmin which works perfectly:

```
SELECT `DBFITCH`.`ISIN`, `RATING_FITCH`as FITCH_RTG
FROM
  (SELECT `ISIN`, MAX(`RATING_DATE`) as LastUpdate 
  FROM `ratings`.`ratingsemissionfitch` GROUP BY ISIN) as LAST
  INNER JOIN `ratings`.`ratingsemissionfitch` as DBFITCH
  ON
  DBFITCH.`ISIN`= LAST.`ISIN` 
  AND DBFITCH.`RATING_DATE`=LAST.LastUpdate
```

In php, the following code wich doesn't run :

```
$sql="CREATE VIEW ratings.rtgemissfitch AS 
SELECT DBFITCH.ISIN, RATING_FITCH as FITCH_RTG
FROM 
  (SELECT ISIN, MAX(RATING_DATE) as LastUpdate 
  FROM ratings.ratingsemissionfitch GROUP BY ISIN) as LAST
  INNER JOIN ratings.ratingsemissionfitch as DBFITCH
  ON
  DBFITCH.ISIN= LAST.ISIN 
  AND DBFITCH.RATING_DATE=LAST.LastUpdate"; 
  $req = $bdd->exec($sql);
```

Let me please show an other example ...

I can't be able to create this view in php (whereas i can in phpmyadmin)

```
$sql="CREATE VIEW ratings.rtgemissfitch AS
SELECT derivedtable. ISIN
FROM
(SELECT ISIN, MAX(Date_Notation_Emission) FROM ratings.ratingsemissionfitch as derivedtable GROUP BY ISIN) ";
```

But i can do this in php :

```
$sql="CREATE VIEW ratings.rtgemissfitch AS
(SELECT ISIN, MAX(Date_Notation_Emission) FROM ratings.ratingsemissionfitch as derivedtable GROUP BY ISIN) ";
```

I really don't understand..
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the logs?  Could be that the MySQL user is different in those two instances.

Comment: 1) They aren't the same query. They aren't even the same type of query (`SELECT` vs `CREATE VIEW`) 2) How exactly does it fail to work?

Comment: enable error reporting in your $bdd class. there is no other way.

Comment: on php you are creating a view and on mysql you are runing a query. The create view will not return a recordset.

Answer (score 0):

your database user probably doesnt have privilege to run

```
CREATE VIEW
```

?